# Is the iOS "Exclamation" Badge/Button available for use within an App?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I suspect that the answer is 'no' - but perhaps I'm missing something in the api...

I'm aware of the constant UIButtonTypes for UIButton:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

But I've also seen Apple use the exclamation badge within their apps, for example, the Reminders app:

[image]

Does anyone know if that button/badge is available?

Or am I making my own?

Comment: I believe it's not.. You should make your own, I don't think it requires much skill to do it. Or you may find it with a quick search. I'll let you know if I find it in my regular sources ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you won't be able to use this button directly.

I don't think you can point to any source to say this, but from my own experience, I never found this button.

But, what you can do, is create or find the button's image. The second option is the easiest one ;)

I found this, giving you all iOS' images (iOS 4.3, but still good) : [All stock iOS 4.3 UI Images](http://jailbreakzone.com/2011/04/09/download-all-stock-ios-4-3-ui-image-including-emoji/).

Or you may use directly these normal/selected retina images (comming from the above link) : [image: failure@2x] [image: failure-pressed@2x]

And the non-retina versions : [image: failure] [image: failure-pressed]

Quick note, you may want to use this button very carefully. As it is a system image, you must use it the way iOS uses it. If you try to use it in an unappropriate context, your app may get rejected by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 1) Re: being cautious with use... I intend to use it in the same way as the example image above - to alert the user that an address did not yield a valid coordinate (via CLGeocoder) 2) Re: the images you found... do you think it's allowed to use those as they are? Or do you think Apple would look more favourably on my own, hand-drawn versions? Cheers, Gavin

Comment: 1) You're fine, it's just you shouldn't use it as an "Add Contact" button or something unrelated to a warning, but unless you're completely stupid, you won't, lol and 2) doesn't seem like a problem to me.. You're making your app even more integrated to the system's UI guidelines when using these images, so that would be dumb of them to bother you with that. But if they do reject your app, you'll be left with the first option ;) Good luck on your app !